# java, How to calculate degree from tan

Tags: java, degrees

I'm using java. I have a tan value.
I really surprise that I can't find a way to turn it into degree.
I already search but only find a way to turn degree into tan.
please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`double atan(double tangent)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan(double)) which, given the tangent, will return the angle in radians.

From there, you can simply multiply it by `180 / PI` to get degrees or, better yet, use the inbuilt [double toDegrees(double radians)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toDegrees(double)).

In other words, something like (assuming you've bought in `java.lang.Math`):

```
double degs = toDegrees(atan(tangent));
```

Comment: atan actually gives the angle as radians, so you have to multiply the result with 180.0 to get the corresponding value in degrees

Comment: @pnkkr, good point, though it's `180/PI` - have added that to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

tan^-1 of value and some more text because it's too short.

Comment: Your *calculator* may have a `tan^-1` button but I don't think Java is similarly belssed :-)

Comment: You're not searious, are you? That's the notation for the inverse of tangent http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangent.html also denoted as arctan as you said.

Comment: Actually, I *am* serious. The question was about *Java.* While your answer may be educational for other purposes, it's not really that helpful in answering the specific question.

Comment: You appear to have missed the point. That link is actually quite good if you're wanting to learn trigonometry but it seems a little deficient in actually trying to figure out *how* to get the arctan from Java (other than perhaps providing an extra search term to look for).  In any case, I don't see much point in arguing the case, we'll let the swarm decide.